# find local maximum/minimum of function $f(x,y)=x+y+4\sin x \sin y$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have this task: find local maximum/minimum of function $f(x,y)=x+y+4\sin x \sin y$.

Now I have found partial derivatives:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 1+4\cos x \sin y$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 1+4\cos y \sin x$

$\cos x \sin y=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\cos y \sin x =-\frac{1}{4}$

But from here I am having trouble finding stationary points, if anyone could help I would be grateful!

Comment: Hint, maybe: the sum and difference fornulae.

Comment: @SeanRoberson right, I could write it as $sin(x-y)=0$ perhaps?

Comment: Correct. Now deduce where the critical points are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)\iff  \begin{cases}\cos(x)\sin(y)=-1/4\\ \sin(x)\cos(y)=-1/4\end{cases}$, if and only if $\begin{cases}\sin(x-y)+\sin(x+y)=-1/2,\\ \sin(x-y)-\sin(x+y)=1/2  \end{cases}$. Thus, $\sin(x-y)=0$ iff $x-y=\pi N$  or $\sin(x+y)=-1/2$ iff $x+y=2\pi M+\frac{7\pi}{6}$ with $N$ and $M$ to be an integers.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer! Just one quick question I don't really see how did you get $sin(x+y)=-\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: It should be $-1/2$. It was a typo, but I fixed that, just right now.

Comment: okay, thank you!